# Sortear letras de forma aleatória

Tags: python

Sei gerar números, mas letras como faço para gerar tipo `AB BC AEEE`, por exemplo.

```
import random

import string

for j in range(40,100):

print(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))
```

Neste código gero uma letra minúscula. Preciso 4 letras por turma número de turmas esta entre 40 a 100

Comment: Já pensou em chamar a função `random.choice` 4 vezes?

Comment: deu certo porem elas nao estao em linha reta como faco para colocalos em linha reta posso usar print end mas como ?

Answer (score 2):

O que você precisa fazer é basicamente chamar a função `random.choice` o número de vezes que você quer sortear uma letra. Como você precisa 4 letras: 4 vezes.

```
import random
import string

letras = string.ascii_uppercase

for turma in range(40, 100):
    codigo = ''.join(random.choice(letras) for _ in range(4))
    print('Turma', turma, 'possui o código', codigo)
```

Porém, isso não garante que os códigos serão únicos, podendo duas ou mais turmas possuírem o mesmo código.

Comment: deu certo obrigado

Comment: Complementando o que o Anderson disse, para que os números não se repitam é preciso armazenar as letras em alguma estrutura, como uma lista, para que seu for cheque se existe a ocorrência da determinada letra dentro da lista. Dessa forma elimina-se a duplicidade de letras sorteadas.